# Django Sum by category

Tags: python, django, sum, aggregate, price

Sorry if the question has already been asked elsewhere.
I have a travel tool.
I have my travel model, containing the activity model. Each activity has a category and a price. I would like to add up the prices of the activities for each category, and I admit I am stuck.

models.py :

```
class Activity(models.Model):
    TRANSPORT = 'Transport'
    HEBERGEMENT = 'Hébergement'
    RESTAURATION = 'Restauration'
    LOISIR = 'Loisir'

    ROLE_CHOICES = (
        (TRANSPORT, 'Transport'),
        (HEBERGEMENT, 'Hébergement'),
        (RESTAURATION, 'Restauration'),
        (LOISIR, 'Loisir'),
    )
    category = models.CharField(max_length=30, choices=ROLE_CHOICES)
    trip = models.ForeignKey(Trip, null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
    place = models.ForeignKey(Place, null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
    date_start = models.DateField(default=date.today)
    time_start = models.TimeField(auto_now=False, auto_now_add=False, null=True, blank=True)
    date_end = models.DateField(default=date.today)
    time_end = models.TimeField(auto_now=False, auto_now_add=False, null=True, blank=True)
    visitor = models.ManyToManyField(Character)
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=5, decimal_places=2, null=True, blank=True)
    prepaid = models.BooleanField(null=True)
    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = "Activities"
```

views.py :

```
def travel_detail(request, travel_id):
    travel = get_object_or_404(Trip, id=travel_id)
    activities = Activity.objects.filter(trip_id=travel_id)
    travellers = travel.traveller.all().order_by("last_name", "first_name")
    prices = Activity.objects.aggregate(Sum('price'))
    template = 'travel/travel_detail.html'
    context = {
        'travel': travel,
        'activities' : activities,
        'travellers' : travellers,
        'prices' : prices,
        }
    return render(request, template, context)
```

template :

```
{% for price in prices %}

   {{prices}}

{% endfor %}
```

My template returns this for now:
{'price__sum': Decimal('43.6000000000000')}

Comment: Maybe `prices = Activity.objects.aggregate(Sum('price'))["price__sum"]`?

Comment: Thank you, but my only result is :
Exception Value: 'decimal.Decimal' object is not iterable

Comment: Adding up on @JPG's answer, just use `{{ prices }}` and remove `{% for price in prices %}`

Comment: Thanks, I got the total! However, how do I calculate for each category?